# New ALTERNATOR + BATTERY yet car STILL won't START! :'(

Tags: battery, starting, alternator, mercedes-benz

I have a 2001 Mercedes Benz E320. It was running fine and I got a dash warning to "check battery/alternator for low power" and then about a mile later the car died. I have a portable generator so I gave myself a jump and the car started but died about a mile down the road. I got it towed and bought a new alternator for it. CAR STILL WOULDN'T START, so I bought a new battery for it. Car still won't start! HELP!!!!

Comment: does the car crank?

Comment: Need to have battery voltage measurements.   Also replacement of battery and alternator may not solve all charging problems, I believe that year and model has an external regulator.

Answer (score 2):

Your climate control unit has a hidden menu that will allow you to verify voltage. Take a look at this video, it will show you how to access the menu.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcWFvfRvJH8

If the electrical system is healthy (sufficient voltage, strong cranking, spark verified) then the next step is to verify you have sufficient fuel pressure.